# Terminal does not work/start (error creating child process)

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I want to clean the cache and trash files on my laptop. As I tried to type

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

or

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I got an error message on the Terminal saying:

```
There was an error creating child process for this terminal
```

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 (upgraded from 14.04) on a Toshiba Satellite.

This is the error I get:

[image: image of a terminal with the error message quoted above]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check if the following helps: Click profile preferences, go to tab "command", untick "run a custom command", exit and relaunch the terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your terminal profile is trying to run an empty shell command - choose the 'Profile Preferences' button and then navigate to the 'Title and Command' tab and make sure that the 'Run a custom command instead of my shell' is **not** selected (or if it *is* selected, that it contains the path to a valid shell program)

[image: gnome-terminal profile preferences]

Comment: Thank you, @STEELDRIVER.
What you suggested did fix the issue, nevertheless I noticed that Ubuntu began acting up ever since the problem began (probably because of something I installed / uninstalled during the days prior and after my question -maybe the upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10) and I decided to reinstall 14.04