# I cannot download from Ubuntu Software and failed to fix child error

Tags: command-line, vpn

I have currently Ubuntu 16.04. I cannot access the terminal to place commands. The terminal is taken up this error message: `[There was an error creating the child process for this terminal]` even when I close it. Below is result from attempting to install tinc VPN.

```
graeme@graeme-ThinkCentre:~$  sudo snap connect tinc-vpn:network-manager
graeme@graeme-ThinkCentre:~$  sudo snap connect tinc-vpn:network-observe
graeme@graeme-ThinkCentre:~$   sudo snap connect tinc-vpn:network-setup-control
graeme@graeme-ThinkCentre:~$ /var/snap/tinc-vpn/
-bash: /var/snap/tinc-vpn/: Is a directory
graeme@graeme-ThinkCentre:~$  sudo mkdir /var/snap/tinc-vpn/tinc
graeme@graeme-ThinkCentre:~$   sudo chown username:username /var/snap/tinc-vpn/tinc -R
chown: invalid user: ‘username:username’
graeme@graeme-ThinkCentre:~$  sudo chmod 775 /var/snap/tinc-vpn/tinc -R
graeme@graeme-ThinkCentre:~$ sudo --pidfile=/run/shm/snap.tinc-vpn.tinc.pid
sudo: unrecognized option '--pidfile=/run/shm/snap.tinc-vpn.tinc.pid'
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
            [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] file ...
graeme@graeme-ThinkCentre:~$ sudo -c /var/snap/tinc-vpn/tinc/(netname)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: Please add link to the instruction which you are trying to follow. Both `sudo --pidfile=/run/shm/snap.tinc-vpn.tinc.pid` and  `sudo -c /var/snap/tinc-vpn/tinc/(netname)` are incorrect commands.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "add a link to the instruction  which you are trying to follow"?

Comment: As I stated originally, I have been trying to install A VPN from Ubuntu software. I am able to install but when I attempt to launch the above error comes up on the terminal.

Comment: Close voters. Crafted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason that you can't install tinc VPN from the software center is that you don't have the [Universe Repository enabled](https://askubuntu.com/a/148645/225694) After enabling it you should be able to install tinc normally as it's [freely available for your version of Ubuntu in the Universe repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/tinc). A quick glance at your commands and output indicates that you've misunderstood the instructions. For example `sudo chown username:username /var/snap/tinc-vpn/tinc -R` in this context username means **your username** so in your case the command would be `sudo chown graeme:graeme /var/snap/tinc-vpn/tinc -R` based upon your output and prompt. As far as the error creating child process for the terminal you may find [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/545220/225694) useful. You may also wish to go over the instructions again as shown below:

[image: tinc VPN instructions]